# do scheduled Celery task still in progress when the django app will be deployed again

Tags: django, asynchronous, celery, scheduled-tasks

I am new to Scheduling jobs in Django. I am using celery for the asynchronous task. My question is if I have made a task which starts when a user clicks on a button. So my website is running and it has many scheduled task in the background which will be executed at the assigned time. But before their execution, if I will redeploy my app (a new version) to the server again with some changes (not related to the things that celery needs) then will the previous tasks be still in progress or they will be terminated due to environment updation process on the server?

I am using Django 2.1
deployment on AWS ElasticBeanstalk using the command line interface to deploy the application.

PS: please comment if Question is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally yes (with the assumption you run them on server with supervisor or something similar, not with session terminal that you stop), they would still keep running because Celery tasks are in separate process with separate workers getting task done.